# Find the third column for the complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the third column of the matrix below so that the matrix is unitary.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{√3} & \frac{i}{√2} & a_{13}\\
\frac{1}{√3} & 0 & a_{23} \\
\frac{i}{√3} & \frac{1}{√2} & a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

find $(a_{13},a_{23},a_{33})$

So I couldn't move a pencil here. Because the question also asks

"How much freedom in column 3?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that the conjugate transpose of this matrix is also its inverse: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix

Comment: I tried using that of course.

Comment: Calculating the upper left element of $AA^T$ gives $1/3-1/2+a_{13}^2$. Because $AA^T=E$ we get $a_{13}=\pm i/\sqrt{6}$. Try calculating another elements and get an answer.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann It would be $1/3 + 1/2 + a^2_{13} = 1$, since you want to complex conjugate transpose of $A$

Comment: @Xenidia, you might want to update your question to include an explanation of where you got stuck with this approach.

Comment: @harvey yes, you are right, thanks